# What is the difference between "Do you interest" and "...interested in" something?

Tags: grammar, questions

I want to ask my friend about interest in engineering a system. How can I ask him?

> Do you interest in the system?

or

> Do you interested in the system?

Which phrase is correctly used?

Comment: "Do you interest [...]" can be correct, if in a usage such as "do you interest their engineering team?", which is a correct but mildly awkward way of asking if their engineering team *is interested in you* (for example, if the team wants to hire you).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Neither is correct.**

You have the verb "to interest" backwards. Here is the structure:

> [subject] interests [object]

It is the **object** of the verb that has the feeling of interest. The object gives attention to the subject. The object feels excited about the subject.

So in your case, it should be:

> Does [something] interest you?

Your other form, "interested in", is used in with the passive of the same verb, "to be interested". You could say:

> Are you interested in [something]?

And both of these would be correct.

Comment: well... fancy that

Answer (score 4):

None of your phrases are correct. You may ask

> - Are you interested in the system?
> - Do you have any interest in the system?

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know :)  I need to remember those phrases.

Comment: If you have difficulties composing questions you can check [This](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/asking-questions-in-english/) link to develop a general idea.